# Tymon's JWTAuth not adding custom claims when generating token in Laravel

Tags: laravel, jwt

I am using the **tymon/jwt-auth library** in my Laravel application to generate JSON Web Tokens (JWT). I am trying to add a custom claim (**purpose**) to the token when a user logs in and needs to reset their password. However, when I inspect the generated token, the custom claim is missing.

Here's the relevant code from my **AuthController**:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    try {
        if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 400);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }

    $user = JWTAuth::user();

    if ($user->must_reset_password) {
        $resetToken = JWTAuth::fromUser($user, ['purpose' => 'password_reset']);
        
        return response()->json(['status' => 'must_reset_password', 'resetToken' => $resetToken], 401);
    }
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}

public function resetPassword(Request $request)
{
    $token = $request->get('resetToken');
    $newPassword = $request->get('new_password');
    $confirmPassword = $request->get('confirm_password');

    try {
        $user = JWTAuth::setToken($token)->authenticate();
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_token'], 400);
    }

    $payload = JWTAuth::getPayload($token);
   
    if ($payload['purpose'] !== 'password_reset') {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_token_purpose'], 400);
    }

    if ($newPassword === $confirmPassword) {
        $user->password = bcrypt($newPassword);
        $user->must_reset_password = false;
        $user->save();
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'passwords_do_not_match'], 400);
    }

    return response()->json(['status' => 'password_reset_successful']);
}
```

When I call the **login** method, I get the following response:

```
{
    "status": "must_reset_password",
    "resetToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjgwMDAvYXBpL2F1dGgvbG9naW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2OTU3NDEzMzUsImV4cCI6MTY5NTc0NDkzNSwibmJmIjoxNjk1NzQxMzM1LCJqdGkiOiJXSGI4c1pjQU1vM25RRjVmIiwic3ViIjoiMSIsInBydiI6IjIzYmQ1Yzg5NDlmNjAwYWRiMzllNzAxYzQwMDg3MmRiN2E1OTc2ZjcifQ.2rsQQJQ2O2g1PqqDsI4CMwApZlBkyLZQOKj9JmDmg9M"
}
```

Upon decoding the **resetToken**, I get the following payload:

```
{
  "iss": "http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login",
  "iat": 1695741335,
  "exp": 1695744935,
  "nbf": 1695741335,
  "jti": "WHb8sZcAMo3nQF5f",
  "sub": "1",
  "prv": "23bd5c8949f600adb39e701c400872db7a5976f7"
}
```

As you can see, the purpose claim is missing. I've checked the config/jwt.php for anything unusual and tried explicitly setting the custom claim, but nothing seems to work.

What might be the reason for the custom claim not being added, and how can I resolve this?